# Xcode showing error 'No such module' even though I've installed Cocoapods and installed pod file of Dialogflow

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dialogflow-es

[image]

I've been making a chatbot using Dialogflow formerly Api.AI but now encountering error while integrating the project to my app written in Swift in Xcode. I'd installed cocoapods using terminal "sudo gem install cocoapods" and using [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/api-ai-cocoa-swift) version of Dialogflow to create the podfile.

All gone well but now when I'm importing inside Xcode in my app's AppDelegate.swift file using **import ApiAI** or **import AI** Xcode is showing me error that **No such module**. Please refer to image.

And on GitHub [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/api-ai-cocoa-swift) library which is written in Swift, showing that it has depreciated and asking me to refer to *[API.AI's Apple Client library](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-apple-client)* which is in Obj-C and unfortunately I've no expertise in Obj-C.

Comment: Please can you format your code as text in the question rather than an image

Comment: On the left menu, Open Pods/Frameworks folders, and checks fir the AI framework or whatever named it's named. Check if it's correctly imported.

Comment: @TCouch here it goes. Also please refer to image if possible.

`import UIKit`
`import ApiAI`
`import AI`

Comment: @Larme https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1J3v.png Please see this.

Answer (score 12):

After installing a pod using Cocoa Pods, you must from that point forward open the workspace rather that the project file.  The icons will appear differently in your project like so:

[image]

In the image you provided is clearly showing that you have opened the project file not the workspace one.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I was straggling for a couple of days because of this silly mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Pods Build settings and set **Build Active Architecture Only** to **NO**. This always helps while using pods. After that clean the project once and then build.

Comment: I did what you say and I encountered these errors, have a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H3vt.png

Comment: You need to import the file instead of using @class declaration for AfNetworking file

Answer (score 2):

After installing pod you should clean project (shift + command + k) and then builds (command + b) in it a few times. Repeat it a few times if it is not still working.

Hope this help!

Comment: clean it until you see no error, and build it again

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this answer. This helped me solve the problem.