# Swift - Modules not loading or directories can't be found on new install

Tags: ios, swift

forgive my ignorance I am not too familiar with SWIFT but my developers sent me the package for one of our iOS apps. I wanted to make a small adjustment but everytime it's run it cannot find all the modules associated with Cocopods

When I originally received the files it came with a podfile and podfile.lock
I installed cocopods then in the directory I tried
pod install

When I try to compile it none of the modules can be found.

I tried removing the podfile and podfile.lock even starting from scratch doing a pod init and replacing the text.
I tried a
pod update and still no luck either. Any ideas what I need to be doing ?

Comment: open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

Comment: Check this url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058092/xcode-showing-error-no-such-module-even-though-ive-installed-cocoapods-and-in/50059038#50059038  please open xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

So the answer of open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj did the trick. Thanks